# If attribute exist, print children description

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I have part of some xml file (for example):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- created at 2017-03-03 11:35:02 -->
<UANodeSet xmlns="http://foundation.org/UA/2011/03/NodeSet.xsd" xmlns:uax="http://foundation.org/UA/20/02/Types.xsd">
    <UAVariable NodeId="ns=1;s=AGENT.OBJECTS.OCP.Data.State" BrowseName="1:State" DataType="UInt16" AccessLevel="7" UserAccessLevel="7" Historizing="true">
        <DisplayName Locale="en">State</DisplayName>
        <Description Locale="en">OCP7.(CONN)</Description>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent" IsForward="false">ns=1;s=AGENT.OBJECTS.OCP.Data</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">BaseVariableType</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=KomunikationInput</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasNotifier">ns=1;s=Komunikation.Data.State.failure</Reference>
        </References>
        <Value>
            <uax:UInt16>0</uax:UInt16>
        </Value>
    </UAVariable>
    <UAObject NodeId="ns=1;s=AGENT.OBJECTS.LOGIN" BrowseName="1:LOGIN">
        <DisplayName Locale="en">LOGIN</DisplayName>
        <Description Locale="en">LOGIN</Description>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent" IsForward="false">ns=1;s=AGENT.OBJECTS</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">FolderType</Reference>
        </References>
    </UAObject>
    <UAObject NodeId="ns=1;s=AGENT.OBJECTS.F01" BrowseName="1:F01">
        <DisplayName Locale="en">F01</DisplayName>
        <Description Locale="en">F01</Description>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent" IsForward="false">ns=1;s=AGENT.OBJECTS</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">FolderType</Reference>
        </References>
    </UAObject>
    <UAObject NodeId="ns=1;s=AGENT.OBJECTS.F01.1" BrowseName="1:1">
        <DisplayName Locale="en">1</DisplayName>
        <Description Locale="en">1</Description>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent" IsForward="false">ns=1;s=AGENT.OBJECTS.F01</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">ns=1;s=ObjectTypes.PROJECT.Forder</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=ObjectTypes.PROJECT.Forder.Overview</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=ObjectTypes.PROJECT.Forder.Info_Display</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=ObjectTypes.PROJECT.Forder.Version</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=ObjectTypes.PROJECT.Forder.Info_Display_Mobile</Reference>
        </References>
    </UAObject>
    <UAObject NodeId="ns=1;s=AGENT.OBJECTS.F01.1.Data" BrowseName="1:Data">
        <DisplayName Locale="en">Data</DisplayName>
        <Description Locale="en">Data</Description>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent" IsForward="false">ns=1;s=AGENT.OBJECTS.F01.1</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">FolderType</Reference>
        </References>
    </UAObject>
    <UAVariable NodeId="ns=1;s=AGENT.OBJECTS.F01.1.Data.State" BrowseName="1:State" DataType="Boolean" ValueRank="1" AccessLevel="7" UserAccessLevel="7" Historizing="true">
        <DisplayName Locale="en">State</DisplayName>
        <Description Locale="en">State</Description>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent" IsForward="false">ns=1;s=AGENT.OBJECTS.F01.1.Data</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">BaseVariableType</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=ObjectTypes.PROJECT.Forder.Data.State.RelMirrorInput</Reference>
        </References>
        <Value>
            <uax:ListOfBoolean>
                <uax:Boolean>false</uax:Boolean>
                <uax:Boolean>false</uax:Boolean>
                <uax:Boolean>false</uax:Boolean>
                <uax:Boolean>false</uax:Boolean>
                <uax:Boolean>false</uax:Boolean>
                <uax:Boolean>false</uax:Boolean>
                <uax:Boolean>false</uax:Boolean>
                <uax:Boolean>false</uax:Boolean>
            </uax:ListOfBoolean>
        </Value>
    </UAVariable>
</UANodeSet>
```

And I want to write script, if children have attribute `HasNotifier`, than print `OCP7.(CONN)`.
I writed xpath, but it's not working. The question is why is not working, or what I'm doing wrong ?

```
//*[namespace-uri() = 'http://foundation.org/UA/2011/03/NodeSet.xsd'][local-name() = 'Reference'][@ReferenceType = 'HasNotifier']/../../Description[@Locale="en"]
```

It's not a duplicate, no one can help me (give tips or solution).
That's why, can be that lxml have some bug - the question whose, or realy lxml have some bugs.

Comment: The code works fine for me, except in the line 3 of the xml file, a quotation mark is missing.

Comment: I test your code on both Python2 and Python3, and no error occurs. Did you open the correct xml file? What's the version of you lxml?

Comment: I have Python 3.4.4
and lxlm 3.6.4

Comment: I tested it with python 3.4.3 and lxml 3.6.4 but no error occured as well. You may test the xpath step by step to find where the error occurs. e.g. `//Reference[@ReferenceType="HasNotifier"]` at first, and then `//Reference[@ReferenceType="HasNotifier"]/../` and so on.

Comment: If I use `//Reference[@ReferenceType="HasNotifier"]` I have no error, only emtpy array `[]` as result.
And with this `//Reference[@ReferenceType="HasNotifier"]/../` i have error : `lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression`

This path does't work also on this website: `http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html`

Comment: This path is also without error: `//Reference[@ReferenceType="HasNotifier"]/../../Description[@Locale="en"]` empty array.

So, how to print this what I'm looking for ?

Comment: Check correctness of provided `xml` sample. If to replace `UANodeSet xmlns="` (note one double-quote) with `UANodeSet xmlns=""` (two double quotes) then you'll get `<Description Locale="en">OCP7.(CONN)</Description>`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. After added one quotes xpath working.
But my second mistake, between the two quotes should be this address of `http: // foundation.org / UA / 2011/03 / NodeSet.xsd`
And after adition address, xpath not work again.
How should i change my xpath ? (above xml file are updated)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it a xpath (lxml) bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803464/is-it-a-xpath-lxml-bug)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, no one can help me (give tips or solution).
That's why, can be that lxml have some bug - the question whose, or realy lxml have some bugs.

Comment: WHY is it not a duplicate? I explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/42804359/407651 that you have to use `*[local-name() = 'Description']`. Now you are asking about that same bad XPath here too.